# Queries created by method names report errors when using spring boot 3.0 and spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

When the project started, an error was reported, but everything functioned properly

No error is reported under spring boot 2.7 normally

spring boot 3.0.1+spring data jpa 3.0.1 creat By Spring Initializr

Exception

```
2023-01-18T11:33:35 | DEBUG | main | org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean | Initializing JpaMetamodelMappingContext…
2023-01-18T11:33:35 | DEBUG | main | org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean | Finished initializing JpaMetamodelMappingContext
2023-01-18T11:33:35 | DEBUG | main | org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler | Creating new EntityManager for shared EntityManager invocation
2023-01-18T11:33:35 | DEBUG | main | org.hibernate.stat.internal.StatisticsInitiator | Statistics initialized [enabled=false]
2023-01-18T11:33:35 | DEBUG | main | org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler | Creating new EntityManager for shared EntityManager invocation
2023-01-18T11:33:35 | DEBUG | main | org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport | Initializing repository instance for com.example.testjpa.repository.FristRepository…
2023-01-18T11:33:35 | DEBUG | main | org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler | Creating new EntityManager for shared EntityManager invocation
2023-01-18T11:33:36 | DEBUG | main | org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.NamedQuery | Looking up named query FristEntity.findByName
2023-01-18T11:33:36 | DEBUG | main | org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl | JDBC transaction marked for rollback-only (exception provided for stack trace)
java.lang.Exception: exception just for purpose of providing stack trace
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.markRollbackOnly(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.buildNamedQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1003)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createNamedQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:866)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createNamedQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:126)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:360)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy105.createNamedQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.NamedQuery.hasNamedQuery(NamedQuery.java:115)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.NamedQuery.lookupFrom(NamedQuery.java:144)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:180)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:252)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:95)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:88)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:88)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:357)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:229)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:113)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1797)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1747)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:59)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:47)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1386)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:191)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:241)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$10(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:382)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$11(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:376)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:289)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:288)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:278)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
2023-01-18T11:33:36 | DEBUG | main | org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.NamedQuery | Did not find named query FristEntity.findByName
2023-01-18T11:33:36 | DEBUG | main | org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler | Creating new EntityManager for shared EntityManager invocation
2023-01-18T11:33:36 | DEBUG | main | org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport | Finished creation of repository instance for com.example.testjpa.repository.FristRepository.
2023-01-18T11:33:36 | DEBUG | main | org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory | Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'data-jpa.repository-aot-processor'
2023-01-18T11:33:36 | DEBUG | main | org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory | Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration'
2023-01-18T11:33:36 | DEBUG | main | org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory | Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.data.web.config.ProjectingArgumentResolverRegistrar'
2023-01-18T11:33:36 | DEBUG | main | org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory | Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration'
2023-01-18T11:33:36 | DEBUG | main | org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory | Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'spring.info-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoProperties'
2023-01-18T11:33:36 | DEBUG | main | org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory | Autowiring by type from bean name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration' via constructor to bean named 'spring.info-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoProperties'
2023-01-18T11:33:36 | DEBUG | main | org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory | Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateConfiguration'
2023-01-18T11:33:36 | DEBUG | main | org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory | Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'jdbcTemplate'
2023-01-18T11:33:36 | DEBUG | main | org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory | Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'spring.jdbc-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcProperties'
2023-01-18T11:33:36 | DEBUG | main | org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory | Autowiring by type from bean name 'jdbcTemplate' via factory method to bean named 'dataSource'
2023-01-18T11:33:36 | DEBUG | main | org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory | Autowiring by type from bean name 'jdbcTemplate' via factory method to bean named 'spring.jdbc-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcProperties'
2023-01-18T11:33:36 | DEBUG | main | org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory | Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.NamedParameterJdbcTemplateConfiguration'
2023-01-18T11:33:36 | DEBUG | main | org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory | Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'namedParameterJdbcTemplate'
2023-01-18T11:33:36 | DEBUG | main | org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory | Autowiring by type from bean name 'namedParameterJdbcTemplate' via factory method to bean named 'jdbcTemplate'
2023-01-18T11:33:36 | DEBUG | main | org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory | Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration'
2023-01-18T11:33:36 | DEBUG | main | org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory | Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlInitializationAutoConfiguration'
2023-01-18T11:33:36 | DEBUG | main | org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory | Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskSchedulingAutoConfiguration'
2023-01-18T11:33:36 | DEBUG | main | org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory | Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'taskSchedulerBuilder'
```

Here is the code for my project

Spring Data JPA entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_frist")
public class FristEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = jakarta.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    //Getters and setters....
}
```

Spring Data JPA Repository：

```
public interface FristRepository extends ListCrudRepository<FristEntity,Integer> {

    List<FristEntity> findByName(String name);

}
```

POM.xml(dependencies)：

```
<!--head ignore-->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
<!--ignore-->
```

Thanks for any help !

Comment: I am seeing the same with Spring Boot 3.0.2.  Did you ever find an answer to this question?  Is this an issue, or something that can be ignored?  I do notice that it's logged as a DEBUG message, not ERROR.

Comment: It is pretty annoying.  My eyes are always drawn to things that look like exceptions in the logs so this is distracting when I run my application locally with logging at DEBUG.  So I'm left with tweaking my logging config to eliminate all this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates exception is thrown to trigger to print stack trace.In fact, there is no errors or exceptions.

Comment: Can you explain the part "JDBC transaction marked for rollback-only (exception provided for stack trace)"?